# Scripts in ROS root space?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I am trying to understand the layout of ROS root space , I found that all the files ( or most of them ) of pre-built packages are scripted in python. Although in user built packages, c++ implementation is available I would like to know if it is possible to have a c++ version of the core scripts ? Or are there some of them that can only be scripted in python . Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254793/scripts-in-ros-root-space?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to know if it is possible to have a c++ version of the core scripts ?

If you mean "are they already provided (by OSRF) and can I somehow install them", then: no.

If by "is it possible" you mean: can they be reimplemented, then: yes, probably, but I doubt anyone is going to do that.

> Or are there some of them that can only be scripted in python?

Well .. this is software, so *anything* is possible, but for some things Python is / was just more efficient / natural / easy / more portable, for others C++.

The choice for a particular language also doesn't necessarily only depend on 'objective' metrics, but often times also on the experience and preferences of the involved developers, which in this case I believe preferred Python for some things. Hence large parts are implemented in that language.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0